# Compare value in a specific row and column with the max value from a range in other rows and columns

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe of a few hundred rows and a dozen or so columns. I need to make a new column where every cell is either `True` or `False`, which will be determined by comparing the adjacent value with the max value from a matrix composed of values from rows and columns to which the original value does not belong.

I have attempted to create a list of the values in the matrix via `pandas` and `NumPy`. I've also tried to compile the list by using `openpyxl` with the data in Excel. I just cannot figure out how to reference rows that are not the current one.

To be clear, I want to produce the word `True` in `column F` based on the fact that `6` in cell `E1` is greater than any value in the `A2:D5` matrix:

[image]

The entire F column should be filled with `True` or `False` (*except near the end where there aren't enough values, which will not matter*).

Edit to show actual data:

```
{'Unnamed: 0': [datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 0, 0)], 
'A': [86.3600006103515, 91.1299972534179, 87.9199981689453, 99.4199981689453, 89.8399963378906], 
'B': [86.3600006103515, 91.1299972534179, 87.9199981689453, 99.4199981689453, 89.8399963378906], 
'C': [93.7399978637695, 92.2099990844726, 93.4599990844726, 99.6900024414062, 90.370002746582], 
'D': [85.3799972534179, 89.0100021362304, 86.5299987792968, 91.6999969482421, 85.3199996948242], 
'E': [92.870002746582, 89.8499984741211, 87.8399963378906, 98.1800003051757, 85.6600036621093], 
'F': [91.8566665649414, 88.8299967447916, 87.6700007120768, 93.4633305867513, 88.3333307902018], 
'G': [93.2239990234375, 88.2079986572265, 90.4440002441406, 91.1099975585937, 87.0139999389648], 
'H': [90.1189994812011, 88.8899993896484, 90.7769989013672, 89.4299995422363, 89.4699996948242], 
'I': [91.8989994049072, 93.9099994659423, 91.107999420166, 93.5399993896484, 94.8799995422363], 
'J': [98.1313329060872, 101.261666107177, 95.9039995829264, 100.749666086832, 102.087999471028]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a solution that worked. Note: I ended up making a change to the original request in the post, but anyone trying to solve this same problem should be able to do so with something like:

```
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator

book["N2"] = '=IF(M2=1,IF((C3*1.01)<MAX(C3:F5),"True","False"),"")'
for i in range(3,300):
    this_cell = "N" + str(i)
    book[this_cell] = Translator('=IF(M2=1,IF((C3*1.01)<MAX(C3:F5),"True","False"),"")', origin = 'N2')\
        .translate_formula(this_cell)
```

Comment: Of course, openpyxl requires or code for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` is your *DataFrame*, you can use :

```
df["F"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["E"] > df.drop(x.name).iloc[:, :-1].max().max(), axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   A  B  C  D  E      F
0  5  7  4  3  6   True
1  5  4  1  2  5  False
2  2  2  0  1  3  False
3  4  5  4  4  3  False
4  4  3  2  1  0  False
```

Comment: Thank you, Timeless. Your code does exactly what my example requests. However, when I apply it to my script, it always returns false. I believe this could be happening because in the actual spreadsheet A, B, C, and D are really the 4th - 7th columns and E and F are the 12th and 13th columns. Or maybe it's because there are 300 more rows? I've played around with values in the .iloc[], but have not been successful. I don't understand how your line works well enough to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, again, for your help, Timeless. The first suggestion did not return a value in the F column. The second suggestion again returned all False. Both printed the 300x4 matrix 300 times to the terminal. I also tried replacing .iloc[:, 1:-7] with .iloc[:, ["A", "B", "C", "D"]], but that returned an error--requires numeric. ???

Comment: You should make a minimal reproducible example *as text* with `print(df.sample(5).to_dict("list"))` and add it to your post.

Comment: {'Unnamed: 0': [datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 7, 0, 0)], 'A': [86.3600006103515, 91.1299972534179, 87.9199981689453, 99.4199981689453, 89.8399963378906], 'B': [86.3600006103515, 91.1299972534179, 87.9199981689453, 99.4199981689453, 89.8399963378906], 'C': [93.7399978637695, 92.2099990844726, 93.4599990844726, 99.6900024414062, 90.370002746582],

Comment: 'D': [85.3799972534179, 89.0100021362304, 86.5299987792968, 91.6999969482421, 85.3199996948242], 'E': [92.870002746582, 89.8499984741211, 87.8399963378906, 98.1800003051757, 85.6600036621093], 'F': [91.8566665649414, 88.8299967447916, 87.6700007120768, 93.4633305867513, 88.3333307902018], 'G': [93.2239990234375, 88.2079986572265, 90.4440002441406, 91.1099975585937, 87.0139999389648], 'H': [90.1189994812011, 88.8899993896484, 90.7769989013672, 89.4299995422363, 89.4699996948242],

Comment: 'I': [91.8989994049072, 93.9099994659423, 91.107999420166, 93.5399993896484, 94.8799995422363], 'J': [98.1313329060872, 101.261666107177, 95.9039995829264, 100.749666086832, 102.087999471028]}

Comment: You should include it to your post above. Can you try `df["K"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["I"] > df.drop(x.name).loc[:, ["A", "B", "C", "D"]].max().max(), axis=1)` ? I'm AFK,..

Comment: So, with the real data that is a bit messier, the goal is to create 'K' which compares 'J' of the same row with the maximum value found in 'C', 'D', 'E', and 'F' of the next three rows.

Comment: Sorry--this is my first post. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries but I feel like we're dealing with a moving target. Can you be more specific, please ? Because now, you have two differents logics. The one you have in your initial post and the one you just described in the comment above.

Comment: Sure. Expanding on the comment just above: if 'J ' is greater than any single value in the array created by the next three lines of 'C', 'D', 'E', and 'F', then 'K' is True. Sorry for the confusion.